# gsub - reduce all repeating characters to one instance

Tags: regex, r, gsub

A slightly odd question for you all - I have solved my issue of wishing to replace all repeating characters in a string, but I don't really understand my solution. Example is:

```
txt <- "haarbbbbbbijjjjjan"
gsub("([a-z])\\1+", "\\1", txt)
[1] "harbijan"
```

Is this just matching all repeated instances of each letter (search term + repeats of search term) and replacing them with the searched for letter? Or is this doing something unintended that I don't fully grasp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've declared one group - any symbol between `a` and `z`. `\\1` references this group. Any number of repeatances of this group is substituted into the group value. For example, if group is `a`, then any number of `a`s will be replaced with group value, e.g. with `a`.

Hope I made myself clear =)

Comment: Thank you - the explanation is very handy!

Comment: @Andrew Logninov, How does this change if you want to replace letters that appear repated more than 2 times in a row. For instance, I'd like to replace ``rrr`` by ``r`` but keep ``rr`` unchanged? Thanks.

Comment: @Nestorghh I don't know what language you're using, but in general, this should look somewhat like this: `substitute('r{3,}', 'r', <your_text>)`.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov I'm using ``R``. But I just realized that this code does the job ``gsub('([a-zA-Z]rrr*)\\1+', 'r', mytext)`` The ``substitute`` function in ``R`` seems to carry out others tasks. In what language it's supposed to run your code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Nestorghh It's pseudocode :) You should try `gsub('r{3,}','r',text)`.

Comment: By the way, what's the meaning of ``r{3,}``? Thanks

Comment: @Nestorghh It means symbol ('r' in this case) should repeat 3 or more times.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace letters that appear AT LEAST 3 times (for example), here is my solution (use `{2,}`:

```
gsub("([[:alpha:]])\\1{2,}", "\\1", "Buennaaaa Suerrrtee")
#[1] "Buenna Suertee"
```

As you can see the 4 "a" have been reduced to only 1 a, the 3 r have been reduced to 1 r but the 2 n and the 2 e have not been changed. As suggested above you can replace the [[:alpha:]] by any combination of [a-zA-KM-Z] or similar, and even use the "or" operator | inside the squre brackets [y|Q] if you want your code to affect only repetitions of y and Q.

```
gsub("([a|e])\\1{2,}", "\\1", "Buennaaaa Suerrrtee")
# [1] "Buenna Suerrrtee"
# triple r are not affected and there are no triple e.
```

If you want to replace the repetitions of at least **n** times the same character, then use `{n-1,}`.
If you want to replace that n-repetitions by only **2** times (for example) that character, use `"\\1\\1"` in the replacement.